# TensorflowJs - Rescale image with factor

Tags: javascript, python, opencv3.0, tensorflow.js

Is it possible to achieve the same Python operation in Javascript using TensorflowJs?

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # NOTE: Re-scaling operation as part of the pre-processing step
```

I am trying to run a custom model in the browser, but it requires this preprocessing step before I can feed it to `tensorflowjs`. It requires I rescale the image by a factor of 1/255.

Any idea how I could achieve this?

I can't find anything with `tersorflowjs`, so decided to try with `opencvjs`, but I am not too sure this has the same effect:

```
function rescaleImg(img, canvasId) {
      const src = cv.imread(img);

      let dst = new cv.Mat();

      let dsize = new cv.Size(
        parseFloat((src.rows * (1 / 255)) / 100),
        parseFloat((src.cols * (1 / 255)) / 100)
      );

      cv.resize(src, dst, dsize, 1 / 255, 1 / 255, cv.INTER_AREA);

      cv.imshow(canvasId, dst);
      src.delete();
      dst.delete();
    }
```

I then pass the image to `tensorflowjs` like:

```
const shapeX = 150;
const shapeY = 150;
rescaleImg(image, id);
const canvas = document.getElementById(id);

tensor = tf.browser
 .fromPixels(canvas)
 .resizeNearestNeighbor([shapeX, shapeY])
 .expandDims(0)
 .toFloat();
}

const prediction = await model.predict(tensor).data();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"rescale" and "resize" are two different operations.
"rescale" modifies the pixel value, while "resize" modify the image size (yeah, also pixel value because of interpolation, but it's just a side effect).

To "rescale" the image in OpenCV you use `convertTo` with the optional scaling factor.

Also, when you rescale, you need to be sure to use the correct underlying data type to hold the new values.

Something like this should work:

```
const src = cv.imread(img);
let dst = new cv.Mat();

// rescale by 1/255, and hold values in a matrix with float32 data type
src.convertTo(dst, cv.CV_32F, 1./255.); 

cv.imshow(canvasId, dst);
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I have settle with having the following, using opencvJs:

```
function rescaleImg(img, canvasId) {
      try {
        const src = cv.imread(img);

        let dst = new cv.Mat();

        let dsize = new cv.Size(src.rows, src.cols);

        cv.resize(src, dst, dsize, 1 / 255, 1 / 255, cv.INTER_AREA);

        cv.imshow(canvasId, dst);
        src.delete();
        dst.delete();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error running resize ", e);
        throw e;
      }
    }
```